# Closing gaps in grid layout when grid items are removed

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Is there a way to use grid layout with grid gaps and missing grid-areas without leaving extra gaps in the layout.

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 500px;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'; 
  width: 200px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.a, .b, .c, .d {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}

.a {
  grid-area: a;
}

.b {
  grid-area: b;
}

.c {
  grid-area: c;
}

.d {
  grid-area: d;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="a">A box</div>
    <div class="b">B box</div>
    <div class="d">D box</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="a">A box</div>
    <div class="b">B box</div>
    <div class="c">C box</div>
    <div class="d">D box</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see that there is a gap between B and D when C is absent from the layout.

Other than changing to a flex layout (non-grid display), is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks,
Srikanth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. Remove `grid-template-areas` and its related `grid-area` rules.

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 500px;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  /* grid-template-areas: 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'; */
  width: 200px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.a, .b, .c, .d {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}

/*
.a { grid-area: a; }
.b { grid-area: b; }
.c { grid-area: c; }
.d { grid-area: d; }
*/
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="a">A box</div>
    <div class="b">B box</div>
    <div class="d">D box</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="a">A box</div>
    <div class="b">B box</div>
    <div class="c">C box</div>
    <div class="d">D box</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

When you create a grid using `grid-template-areas`, keep these points in mind:

- `grid-template-areas` creates an [explicit grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#explicit-grids).
- A row is created for every string value. Since you have four strings (`"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, `"d"`), that creates four explicit rows. These rows exist with or without grid items.
- *Explanation:* As the container creates an explicit grid, it does not factor in the existence of grid items. The container creates rows and columns. As these rows and columns intersect they create cells. Cells can be occupied or unoccupied.
- *Think of it this way:* The relationship between grid rows and items is analogous to tracks and trains. The tracks exist with or without trains. In fact, in Grid parlance, [columns and rows are known as "tracks"](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-track-concept). Tracks are just infrastructure.

So your best bet is to switch from explicit rows, which are defined using `grid-template-areas` and/or `grid-template-rows`, to *implicit* rows, which allow the grid algorithm to create row tracks as needed to accommodate items.

If you remove `grid-template-areas` and `grid-area` from your ruleset, the grid will automatically lay out the grid items in a single column (as you have defined), and it has no reason to skip rows/leave gaps. Here's the code again from above:

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 500px;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  /* grid-template-areas: 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'; */
  width: 200px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.a, .b, .c, .d {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}

/*
.a { grid-area: a; }
.b { grid-area: b; }
.c { grid-area: c; }
.d { grid-area: d; }
*/
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="a">A box</div>
    <div class="b">B box</div>
    <div class="d">D box</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="a">A box</div>
    <div class="b">B box</div>
    <div class="c">C box</div>
    <div class="d">D box</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

If you don't want the grid items to consume all free space, then use [**`align-content: start`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content), which overrides the default `align-content: stretch`:

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 500px;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  /* grid-template-areas: 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'; */
  align-content: start; /* new */
  width: 200px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.a, .b, .c, .d {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}

/*
.a { grid-area: a; }
.b { grid-area: b; }
.c { grid-area: c; }
.d { grid-area: d; }
*/
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="a">A box</div>
    <div class="b">B box</div>
    <div class="d">D box</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="a">A box</div>
    <div class="b">B box</div>
    <div class="c">C box</div>
    <div class="d">D box</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Lastly, if you want each implicit row to have a certain height, use [**`grid-auto-rows`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows):

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 500px;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  /* grid-template-areas: 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'; */
  align-content: start; /* new */
  grid-auto-rows: 40px; /* new */
  width: 200px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.a, .b, .c, .d {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}

/*
.a { grid-area: a; }
.b { grid-area: b; }
.c { grid-area: c; }
.d { grid-area: d; }
*/
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="a">A box</div>
    <div class="b">B box</div>
    <div class="d">D box</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="a">A box</div>
    <div class="b">B box</div>
    <div class="c">C box</div>
    <div class="d">D box</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Clear explanation. Great answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `grid-template-areas` this works out of the box

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  width: 200px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin: 1em;
}

.a,
.b,
.c,
.d {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="a">A box</div>
    <div class="b">B box</div>
    <div class="d">D box</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="a">A box</div>
    <div class="b">B box</div>
    <div class="c">C box</div>
    <div class="d">D box</div>
  </div>
</div>
```